# Send photos from Mac to iPhone using iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, photos

I'm  trying to [send photos to my iPhone, using iTunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/202980/87092), but when I select the `Photos` section in iTunes, it shows me this (it doesn't let me choose a folder):

> [image]

---

How can I sync a specific folder containing images on my iPhone?

Comment: The method you link to in your question is only when you're not using iCloud.  It looks from your screenshot that you're using iCloud.  Are you not able to access the photos from *Finder* or from [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com)?

Comment: @fbara I uploaded my photos using `icloud.com`, but I'd like to sync a specific folder—what settings should I change for that?